# ModuleNotFoundError when running pytest and tox

Tags: pytest, maya, packaging, setup.py, tox

I am trying to build template packages for 2 slightly different purposes, they can be found here :

- https://github.com/martinlanton/tox_template_project
- https://github.com/martinlanton/maya_template_project

The first one is a generic template project using tox/pytest/setup.py and works quite fine.
The second one however is for the same purpose but when testing with the interpreter provided with Autodesk Maya.

My problem comes with the second one.
When running the tests using the `tox` command, I get this error :

```
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_maya_test_setup.py ______________________________________________________________________________________________________________ 
ImportError while importing test module 'D:\python\maya_template_project\tests\test_maya_test_setup.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2022\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests\test_maya_test_setup.py:4: in <module>
    from one.module_one import create_sphere
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'one'
========================================================================================================================= short test summary info ========================================================================================================================== 
ERROR tests/test_maya_test_setup.py
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 
============================================================================================================================= 1 error in 0.13s ============================================================================================================================= 
ERROR: InvocationError for command 'C:\Program' 'Files\Autodesk\Maya2022\bin\mayapy' -m pytest (exited with code 2)
_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________ summary __________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
ERROR:   maya2022: commands failed
```

Here is the content of my tox.ini :

```
[tox]
envlist = maya2022
skipdist = True

[testenv:maya2022]
passenv = PYTHONPATH

deps = -rrequirements.txt

commands =
    C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2022\bin\mayapy -m pytest
setenv =
    IN_MAYA = 1
```

As far as I understand, this seems to come from the location of the conftest.py, which forces tox to add the location of the conftest file to sys.path.

I have tried to remove the `skipdist` as mentioned in a few threads, but this had no effect whatsoever on the result (as I suspected anyway, because of the work around mentioned below).

This means that if I update [this line](https://github.com/martinlanton/maya_template_project/blob/main/tests/test_maya_test_setup.py#L4) to `from src.one.module_one import create_sphere`, this fixes the problem and works properly.
However, this is very undesirable as I do not want the `src` package to be importable, but more importantly, I'd like the `one` package to be importable directly as this is the most logical thing to do, but also because this is the intended behavior as explained in [this article](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/goodpractices.html).

So my question is : how do I fix this and get my project working without needing to add the `src` package to my imports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tox` does not care about a `conftest.py`, as this is configuration/collection file for `pytest` fixtures.

Adding or removing `skipdist` from or to a tox.ini file does not make a difference, as this is no valid `tox` setting. I think you meant `skipsdist`, see https://tox.wiki/en/latest/config.html

You probably want to delete the `__init__.py` in your `src` directory - this is meant to be a folder with only your project source in it, ie the one folder. `src` should not be importable.

The specific problem with your setup is, that you install the project with `tox`, but then use a Python interpreter (`C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2022\bin\mayapy`) which has no access to the installed package - that is why you get the `ModuleNotFoundError`.

The reason why `from src.one.module_one import create_sphere` works - at least a bit - is that you invoke `pytest` as a module.

`python -m pytest` makes `pytest` add the current dir to sys path, see https://jugmac00.github.io/til/what-is-the-difference-between-invoking-pytest-and-python-m-pytest/

So, how to fix this?

In general and as far as I know `tox` is not meant to work with custom interpreters.

Maybe you can work around that by manipulating `sys.path` by adding the `one` directory to the path, which is then available to your custom interpreter.

This means that your project needs to work without being installed, and the tests need to be discoverable from the "external" `pytest`.

I cannot determine whether these workarounds are useful and work for you, as I am not familiar with Maya, but I am one of the `tox` developers and what you do is definitely not "maintstream" :-)

P.S.: You could also use the `install_command` to install your package not with `pip` from your `tox` env, but with `pip` from Maya, see https://tox.wiki/en/latest/config.html#conf-install_command and https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/downloads/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2022/ENU/Maya-Scripting/files/GUID-72A245EC-CDB4-46AB-BEE0-4BBBF9791627-htm.html

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment!
Yes I know this is not mainstream, however I cannot use anything else than this interpreter as it comes with a bunch of stuff provided by Autodesk, the developer of Maya.
I have also stumbled (sort of) on that problem before as the Maya interpreter doesn't seem to be compatible with the `basepython` argument : https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/issues/1175
That would obviously be the ideal workflow but this doesn't seem to be supported at the moment (which is fair considering the specifics)

Comment: I will take a look at using the `install_command` as it seems to be the best way to currently do that. I have thought of the `sys.path` solution, but I'd rather not mess with sys.path if I can avoid it, especially just for test purposes.

Comment: I have tried using the following install command :
`C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2022\bin\mayapy -m pip install {maya_template_project}` but this raises the following error : `tox.exception.ConfigError: ConfigError: substitution key 'maya_template_project' not found`.
I'm honestly very confused as to how that command works.

Comment: You are not expected to change the value in curly braces - maybe the description ( https://tox.wiki/en/latest/config.html#conf-install_command ) is not clear enough. You probably want to create a custom command like `C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2022\bin\mayapy -m pip install {packages}`.

Comment: And manipulating `sys.path` - just in your test setup - is nothing I would mind, especially as you have a special setup anyway :-)

Comment: Thanks!
This command `C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2022\bin\mayapy -m pip install {packages}` does seem to work, although only when using the cmd with admin permissions (this is due to the fact that maya's interpreter is under `Program Files` and therefore requires admin permissions to write to it), is there anyway I can set that up in in my tox.ini directly instead of having to open the cmd as admin?

Comment: Also I usually don't mind manipulating sys.path, but the reason I'd rather stay away from it, among other things, is that I am already doing that extensively in other places, AND I'd like that setup to be portable with minimum side effects. That said this is still an option I keep in last resort.

Comment: Basically, running `mayapy -m pytest` is already manipulating the path, see https://jugmac00.github.io/til/what-is-the-difference-between-invoking-pytest-and-python-m-pytest/

If adding the content of the `src` directory to your path fixes your problem, I would prefer that over forcing your users to use admin permissions.

From there on I think I can't help you any further as I neither use Maya nor Windows. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much, I believe that covers it pretty much!